# EventHandler to other control

Tags: c#, visual-studio, event-handling

I have problem with Eventhandler on c# (Visual Studio)

My Code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.lastCreatedPanel++;

    SizeablePanel sp = new SizeablePanel();
    sp.BackColor = Color.Gray;
    sp.Name = "DynamicPanel_" + lastCreatedPanel;
    sp.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;

    Label label = new Label();
    label.Text = "X";
    label.Location = new Point(1, 1);
    label.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(this.Panel_MouseDown);
    label.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(this.Panel_MouseMove);

    sp.Controls.Add(label);
}


private void Panel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) 
    {
        loc = e.Location;
    }
}

private void Panel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Control ctrl = sender as Control;  
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        ctrl.Left += e.X - loc.X;
        ctrl.Top += e.Y - loc.Y;
        table.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

I need run Panel_MouseDown and Panel_MouseMove function for dynamically created panels - not for labels. Label is just control to capture.

How can I do it ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

After you create your panel, just attach the `EventHandlers` like this:

```
var panel = new Panel();

panel.MouseDown += Panel_MouseDown;
panel.MouseMove += Panel_MouseMove;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. In this case label is draggable instead of Panel.. Panels should be draggable when MouseDown event is on label